# How to access Data.Functor.Of?

Tags: haskell, haskell-streaming

I am trying to use the [length](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.6/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming-Char8.html#v:length) function of the `streaming-bytestring` `Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8` library.

I see that the return value has type `Of`, but I am not clear on how to examine it. I tried using `case`, but the compiler says `Not in scope: data constructor ‘O.Of’`, even if I do a qualified import of `Data.Functor.Of`.

How do I examine the value?

Code sample:

```
ghci> let bs = BSSC.string "tiger"            
ghci> bs                                                   
Chunk "tiger" (Empty (()))                                            
ghci> BSSC.length bs                 
6 :> ()                                  
ghci> let len = BSSC.length bs
ghci> :t len
len :: Monad m => m (OO.Of Int ())
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example (a small code fragment with the given error, such that we can see what is going on)?

Comment: You can find out how to construct `Of` by writing `:info Of` in GHCi, or using [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Of).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The constructor of `Of` is called `(:>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Of.html#t:Of):

```
-- | A left-strict pair; the base functor for streams of individual elements.
data Of a b = !a :> b
    deriving (Data, Eq, Foldable, Ord,
              Read, Show, Traversable, Typeable, Generic, Generic1)
infixr 5 :>
```

so you should be able to do something like

```
n :> _ <- length bs
```